# Firebase authentication fails when I don't use "Debug JS Remotly" mode in React Native App

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I made firebase authentication in my react native app. It works well when I use its 'debugging' mode. Its signs up and logs in perfectly. And makes data operations to firebase real-time database well, too. But it must be working without debugging mode. Without debugging mode it gives this error: [image: Click to Image]

I am curious about the solution. Can anyone help? Btw my device is an **android**.

Comment: You're probably getting the error all the time, the only difference is that when debugging, the error's popping up in your browser's console.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's an issue with firebase@5.0.4

1. On your command line run npm install firebase@5.0.3.

**OR**

You have to **import firebase** library as follows as i was having same issue as yours ans following way solved my issue

**USE : -**

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.intializeFirebase();
}

intializeFirebase() {   
/* eslint-disable global-require */     // to disable eslint rule
    const firebase = require('firebase');
/* eslint-enable global-require */    // to enable eslint rule

firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    authDomain: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    databaseURL: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    projectId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    storageBucket: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    messagingSenderId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' });


}
```

**Instead of this :-**

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
```

This will definatley solve your issue.